# NoMethodError when "to" contains a name with unparsable characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

We get people's names from a third party source, some of the last names contain a department suffix such as `"(R&D)"`. When trying to send email, via ActionMailer, we get a `NoMethodError` error originating in the mail gem.

It can be reproduced without ActionMailer as follows:

```rb
to = "Kris Leech <kris@example.com>"
mail = Mail.new { to(to) }
mail[:to].addrs # => [#<Mail::Address]

to = "Kris Leech [TECH] <kris@example.com>"
mail = Mail.new { to(to) }
mail[:to].addrs # => NoMethodError: undefined method `addrs' for Mail::UnstructuredField
```

The presence of the square brackets cause `Mail::UnstructuredField`, which does not respond to `addrs`, to be returned instead of `Mail::StructuredField`.

We can see that there is a parse error:

```rb
mail[:to].errors # => [["To", "Kris Leech [TECH] <kris.leech@example.com>", #<Mail::Field::IncompleteParseError: Mail::AddressList can not parse |Kris Leech [TECH] <kris@example.com>|: Only able to parse up to "Kris Leech ">]]
```

How do I escape or otherwise correct the name part of the "to"?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-10) the name part, when it contains reserved characters, must be quoted.

This is implemented in [Mail::Utilities](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/utilities.rb#L23).

So we can "quote" the name part as such:

```rb
QuoteName = Class.new do
  extend Mail::Utilities

  def self.call(name)
    quote_phrase(name)
  end
end

to = "#{QuoteName.('Kris Leech [TECH]')} <kris@example.com>"
mail = Mail.new { to(to) }
mail[:to].addrs # => [#<Mail::Address]
```